# Concurrency design in image processing

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

I'm new to this topic and I need to design concurrency for a program that includes the following tasks:

1. Load image from the database (100ms)
2. Find some metadata of the image (50ms)
3. Converts the image to grayscale. (100ms)
4. Finds all objects in the greyscale image. (600ms)
5. Crop the parts of the image that contain the object. (100ms / object)
6. Saves the data (original image, metadata and new cropped images) in a database (100ms)

How could I design the program to run in concurrent way?

I found that step 2 is independent of step 3,4,5,6, so it can be run in parallel as follows:

```
1->2     -> 6
   3->4->5
```

However, since task 2 is only 50ms and task 6 need to have all task 2,3,4,5 done to be executed. How can I specify that task 2 need to "wait" for the other tasks?

To run concurrently, what is a reasonable pattern for this problem? And what kind of possible issues may arise?
I'm thinking of a "pipeline pattern" like this. But not sure if there is a more efficient pattern

```
1->2     -> 6
   3->4->5
   1->2     -> 6
      3->4->5
      1->2     -> 6
         3->4->5
...
```

Comment: Lots of possible answers to this, but one way (of many) is C++ standard library [`async` and `future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async): call `async` to start 2 and the 3->4->5 *chain* currently, then 6, `wait`'s on those two futures before starting.

Comment: @Oliver Dain Is there a way to run 3,4,5 each concurrently? I found out they are much more time consuming than the 2nd process.

Comment: You can use seperate threads for each concurent operation. For example you have 3 concurent operation and 3 thread related with them. An operation can call thread2.join(); If it needs thread2 operation to be done. thread2.join(); will wait till thread2 operation complete. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break your workload into tasks with dependencies between them. And use Intel Task Scheduler to execute and automatically parallelize your workload. See [Tutorial : Task Based Programming](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/tutorial-intel-tbb-task-based-programming).

For more insight I cannot recommend enough watching [Plain Threads are the GOTO of todays computing - Hartmut Kaiser - Keynote Meeting C++ 2014](https://youtu.be/4OCUEgSNIAY).